# Cygwin system("pause"); and system("cls"); error

Tags: c++, windows, cygwin

This is my C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
   system("pause");
   system("cls");
   return 0;
}
```

I compile it in cygwin and I have this error: sh: line 1: pause: command not found
sh: line 1: cls: command not found.
I have installed ncurses but it's still not working, could anyone help please?

Comment: Those are Windows-only commands, and Cygwin pretends it's not Windows. Either don't use Cygwin or use some other way to pause and clear the screen.

Comment: this arent compile errors. Your code builds fine.

Comment: Answer from sister site: https://askubuntu.com/questions/773687/systempause-for-linux-g-c

Comment: `system()` is a security nightmare and it's also a pain to interact with the program spawned by `system()` - it should *never* be used.

Comment: Using `ncurses` instead would be a much better option than `system()`.

Comment: If you want to use Windows commands, you could use the native compiler in Visual Studio Community. There it works!

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'd assume OP is completely new to programming if they're struggling with this, setting up and working with ncurses will probably be a bit overwhelming for them.

Comment: Why do you use Cygwin in the first place? It exists to help port Linux programs (those that weren't written in a cross-platform manner) to Windows, but you're not doing that. I wouldn't use it to write any new code without a good reason. Depending on what compiler you like more, choose between [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) (GCC, Clang) and Visual Studio (MSVC, perhaps Clang too).

Comment: There is no executable named `pause` or `cls` command in your PATH. From what shell are you executing your compiled program? From the error message, I conclude that `sh` is used. So for testing, just start an interactive `sh` and try the commands, and after they work, put them into your C++ program.

Comment: BTW, the command to pause execution for a specific time is `sleep`, and for clearing the screen it is `clear`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to run this program, you can use `system("cmd.exe /c pause")` or `system("cmd.exe /c cls")`. However, as others have already pointed out, it may be incomplete or pose security risks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, btw, how do you know about this command? I searched across the Internet and couldn't find anything useful

Comment: @Pavlo In the Cygwin shell environment, when using the `system()` function, you can execute Windows executable files. However, `pause` and `cls` are built-in commands of cmd.exe, not standalone executable files, and thus cannot be executed in the Cygwin shell environment. Therefore, to run these commands, you need to pass `cmd.exe` along with the command `/c pause` or `/c cls` to the `system()` function. This approach is based on a rule of thumb.

Comment: If you wish to use `pause` or `cls` directly, or if there is no specific reason for using Cygwin, it is recommended to consider MSYS2 or Visual Studio, as others have already commented. This is a better choice if you are not concerned with maintaining cross-platform compatibility with Linux.